# Regex to validate image url which may contains extension like jpeg, jpg, gif, png

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex to validate image url which may contains extension like jpeg, jpg, gif, png

I'm using

```
/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp)(\?.*)*$/i
```

but it gives false for `https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4668/as-images.apple.com/is/macbook-air-gallery3-20201110?wid=4000&hei=3072&fmt=jpeg&qlt=80&.v=1603399121000`

I'm expecting a regex which can give true if this extensions like jpg, jpeg, png, gif, webp are present in url.

Comment: Why? Filename extensions don't prove anything. You should ignore the filename entirely and acutally _verify_ that the file is an image file using something like magic-file or try loading it into an image editing library.

Comment: That's because I want Images url from this extensions (jpg, jpeg, png, gif, webp) only @Dai

Comment: Try `/(?:\.|[&?]fmt=)(jpe?g|png|gif|webp)\b/i`

Comment: @Amerjit But you can't trust filename extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to test for URL parameter `fmt=<format>`:

- first example: `fmt=jpeg` in middle
- second example: `fmt=jpeg` at end
- third example: `fmt=bmp` (unsupported format)

```js
const regex = /\bfmt=(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp)(?=(&|$))/;
[
  'https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4668/as-images.apple.com/is/macbook-air-gallery3-20201110?wid=4000&hei=3072&fmt=jpeg&qlt=80&.v=1603399121000',
  'https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4668/as-images.apple.com/is/macbook-air-gallery3-20201110?wid=4000&hei=3072&qlt=80&.v=1603399121000&fmt=jpeg',
  'https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4668/as-images.apple.com/is/macbook-air-gallery3-20201110?wid=4000&hei=3072&fmt=bmp&qlt=80&.v=1603399121000',
].forEach(url => {
  console.log(url + ' => ' + regex.test(url));
});
```

Output:

```
https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4668/as-images.apple.com/is/macbook-air-gallery3-20201110?wid=4000&hei=3072&fmt=jpeg&qlt=80&.v=1603399121000 => true
https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4668/as-images.apple.com/is/macbook-air-gallery3-20201110?wid=4000&hei=3072&qlt=80&.v=1603399121000&fmt=jpeg => true
https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4668/as-images.apple.com/is/macbook-air-gallery3-20201110?wid=4000&hei=3072&fmt=bmp&qlt=80&.v=1603399121000 => false
```

Explanation of regex:

- `\b` -- word boundary
- `fmt=` -- literal `fmt=` parameter (this is to avoid false positives)
- `(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp)` -- logical 'or' of supported file extensions
- `(?=(&|$))` -- positive lookahead for either `&` or end of string

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you'd like to do exactly but this should return `true` :

```js
var text = "https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4668/as-images.apple.com/is/macbook-air-gallery3-20201110?wid=4000&hei=3072&fmt=jpeg&qlt=80&.v=1603399121000";
const regex = new RegExp(/(\W)(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp)(\W)/);
console.log(regex.test(text));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).